# How to connect to RabbitMQ (docker-compose)?

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

Friends, I'm practicing here and developing a system which consists of a webservice and a worker and they communicate to each other through RabbirMQ. It's everything working fine when I run each container separately but when I try to run them through docker-compose, it doesn't work. The connection with the Webservice fails: "dial tcp: lookup rabbitmq on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host ..."

Maybe you guys can help me to find out what I am missing. Here are the credentials:

```
conn, err = amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672")
    if err != nil {
        logErr(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
    }
```

and here is my compose file:

```
version:  '3.3'
services: 
    blur-rabbitmq: 
        image: rabbitmq:3-alpine
        container_name: blur-rabbitmq
        restart: always
        hostname: rabbitmq
        ports: 
            - 5672:5672
            - 15672:15672
        environment:
            # RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: ${RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE}
            RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "guest"
            RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "guest"
            RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "/"
    
    blur-service: 
        depends_on:
            - blur-rabbitmq
        build: .
        container_name: blur-service
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: /Users/marcelo/Desktop/source-images
              target: /source-images
        ports: 
            - 8080:8080

    blur-worker: 
        depends_on:
            - blur-rabbitmq
        build: controller/
        container_name: blur-worker
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: /Users/marcelo/Desktop/source-images
              target: /source-images
            - type: bind
              source: /Users/marcelo/Desktop/blurred-images
              target: /blurred-images
```

And here part of the logs I am getting:

```
Starting blur-rabbitmq ... done
Starting blur-service  ... done
Recreating blur-worker ... done
Attaching to blur-rabbitmq, blur-service, blur-worker
blur-service     | 2020/10/26 01:08:57 dial tcp: lookup rabbitmq on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host: Failed to connect to RabbitMQ
blur-service exited with code 1
blur-worker      | Traceback (most recent call last):
blur-worker      |   File "worker.py", line 34, in <module>
blur-worker      |     main()
blur-worker      |   File "worker.py", line 18, in main
blur-worker      |     connection = BlockingConnection(ConnectionParameters("rabbitmq"))
blur-worker      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 359, in __init__
blur-worker      |     self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
blur-worker      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 450, in _create_connection
blur-worker      |     raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
blur-worker      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/utils/selector_ioloop_adapter.py", line 562, in _resolve
blur-worker      |     result = socket.getaddrinfo(self._host, self._port, self._family,
blur-worker      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
blur-worker      |     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
blur-worker      | socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
blur-service exited with code 1
blur-service exited with code 1
blur-worker      | Traceback (most recent call last):
blur-worker      |   File "worker.py", line 34, in <module>
blur-worker      |     main()
blur-worker      |   File "worker.py", line 18, in main
blur-worker      |     connection = BlockingConnection(ConnectionParameters("rabbitmq"))
blur-worker      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 359, in __init__
blur-worker      |     self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
blur-worker      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 450, in _create_connection
blur-worker      |     raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
blur-worker      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/utils/selector_ioloop_adapter.py", line 562, in _resolve
blur-worker      |     result = socket.getaddrinfo(self._host, self._port, self._family,
blur-worker      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
blur-worker      |     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
blur-worker      | socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
blur-rabbitmq    | Configuring logger redirection
blur-worker exited with code 1
blur-service exited with code 1
blur-rabbitmq    | 2020-10-26 01:09:03.310 [debug] <0.287.0> Lager installed handler error_logger_lager_h into error_logger
blur-rabbitmq    | 2020-10-26 01:09:03.315 [debug] <0.290.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into error_logger_lager_event
blur-rabbitmq    | 2020-10-26 01:09:03.315 [debug] <0.293.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_lager_event
blur-rabbitmq    | 2020-10-26 01:09:03.315 [debug] <0.296.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_channel_lager_event
blur-rabbitmq    | 2020-10-26 01:09:03.315 [debug] <0.299.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_connection_lager_event
blur-rabbitmq    | 2020-10-26 01:09:03.315 [debug] <0.302.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_feature_flags_lager_event
blur-rabbitmq    | 2020-10-26 01:09:03.315 [debug] <0.305.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_federation_lager_event
blur-rabbitmq    | 2020-10-26 01:09:03.315 [debug] <0.308.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_ldap_lager_event
blur-rabbitmq    | 2020-10-26 01:09:03.315 [debug] <0.311.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_mirroring_lager_event
blur-rabbitmq    | 2020-10-26 01:09:03.315 [debug] <0.317.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_queue_lager_event
blur-rabbitmq    | 2020-10-26 01:09:03.315 [debug] <0.314.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_prelaunch_lager_event
blur-rabbitmq    | 2020-10-26 01:09:03.315 [debug] <0.320.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_ra_lager_event
blur-rabbitmq    | 2020-10-26 01:09:03.315 [debug] <0.323.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_shovel_lager_event
blur-rabbitmq    | 2020-10-26 01:09:03.315 [debug] <0.326.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_upgrade_lager_event
blur-rabbitmq    | 2020-10-26 01:09:03.338 [info] <0.44.0> Application lager started on node rabbit@rabbitmq
blur-worker      | Traceback (most recent call last):
blur-worker      |   File "worker.py", line 34, in <module>
blur-worker      |     main()
blur-worker      |   File "worker.py", line 18, in main
blur-worker      |     connection = BlockingConnection(ConnectionParameters("rabbitmq"))
blur-worker      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 359, in __init__
blur-worker      |     self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
blur-worker      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 450, in _create_connection
blur-worker      |     raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
blur-worker      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/utils/selector_ioloop_adapter.py", line 562, in _resolve
blur-worker      |     result = socket.getaddrinfo(self._host, self._port, self._family,
blur-worker      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
blur-worker      |     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
blur-worker      | socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
blur-worker exited with code 1
blur-rabbitmq    | 2020-10-26 01:09:03.810 [debug] <0.283.0> Lager installed handler lager_backend_throttle into lager_event
```

Comment: You have multiple `hostname: rabbitmq` - how would you distinguish between those?

Comment: That was just a copy-paste problem, thanks. It's still not working.

Comment: Has `blur-rabbitmq` started? Does the resolved IP match? Anything interesting in logs?

Comment: Yes all three containers are starting and after that I get: "Attaching to blur-rabbitmq, blur-service, blur-worker
blur-service ... dial tcp: lookup rabbitmq on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host: ...

Comment: I added part of the logs up there! Thanks for the hints!

Comment: "no such host" --- well, in the original question it was a **different** error. It would be helpful if your question reflected the **actual** state of the problem.

Comment: Thats right! This error started being shown after you gave that hint about the hostnames. Thanks once again. I will update the question.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
conn, err = amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@blur-rabbitmq:5672")
```

Connection string should be service name in docker-compose.